# handle pre-existing files with inotify

Tags: linux, events, loops, inotify

I'm monitoring the creation/moved of new files in a directory. 
I'm currently using a simple **ls loop** and I would like to move to **inotify**.

I have one main trouble: how to handle initialization with pre-existing files (in case of crash, reboot, stop, ...) ?

Initially, I just want to monitor for IN_CREATE and IN_MOVED_TO but this won't handle pre-existing files.

Can it be handle natively by inotify?

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you to use [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) which perl program that uses inotify internally.( It is possible to run it as daemon )
When you setup it to watch folder with files , you can simply run `touch *` inside watched folder. This will update timestamps of files and inotify events will trigger.

Be careful with IN_CREATE event if you need to do something with files that are created or moved, because this event will be fired immediately after file has been created. In that case you can use event CLOSE_WRITE which will fire after file has been closed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Now, I'm doing some tests in python with pyinotify. I would like to avoid using touch * or playing with symbolic links. I aim to implement my process in C.